# Is there a way to truncate decimal when adding it to sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, api, entity-framework

I'm trying to truncate a decimal fetched from api and send directly to table in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipes] 
(
    [Id]          INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Uri]         NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Label]       NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Image]       NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Source]      NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Url]         NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [ShareAs]     NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Yield]       DECIMAL(38)   NULL,
    [Calories]    DECIMAL(38)   NULL,
    [TotalWeight] DECIMAL(38)   NULL,
    [TotalTime]   DECIMAL(38)   NULL,
);
```

```
myContext.Recipes.Add(new()
                    {
                        Id = IdForRecipesManually,
                        Calories = hit.recipe.calories,
                        ShareAs = hit.recipe.shareAs,
                        Uri = hit.recipe.uri,
                        Url = hit.recipe.url,
                        Image = hit.recipe.image,
                        Label = hit.recipe.label,
                        Yield = hit.recipe.yield,
                        Source = hit.recipe.source,
                        TotalTime = hit.recipe.totalTime,
                        TotalWeight = Decimal.Truncate(hit.recipe.totalWeight)
                    });
```

But I'm trying to truncate directly when adding value into the `Recipes` table in `myContext` doesn't seem to work since the value does not get truncated after I run the code.

But when trying to truncate variable outside `myContext.Recipes` it works just fine, like this:

```
var temp = Decimal.Truncate(hit.recipe.totalWeight);
```

Is it possible to make this inside `myContext.Recipes`?

Tried to truncate inside `myContext.Recipes` scope but it didn't work as intended.

**EDIT**
The main reason why I decided to truncate the decimal value was because I always stumbled upon this error "argument exception parameter value is out of range decimal", so I then changed the decimal declaration to decimal(38, 30) in both SQL server and in entity framework to handle high precision decimals. It worked for in some
object but in the end I received another error "Coversion overflow".

Comment: Does your `[TotalWeight]` column ever need to be a decimal? If not, I would change the data type at the table level. IE: change the `[TotalWeight]` column to an `INT`  data type.

Comment: I tried it earlier but then I got errors when using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, because the data such as TotalWeight contains only decimals, with high precision.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? From what i can tell, there are no difference in using a temp or setting it directly.

Comment: I also find it strange for it to behave like that. Looking at the value in the database it hasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

What database and database framework do you use to save the Recipe?

If you are using SQL Server and Entity Framework (according to your tags) you don't have to call decimal.Truncate because with the table definition above the decimal will be truncated in the database automatically. (In memory you will still have the decimal places, but in the database they are lost.)

So if you reload the Recipe TotalWeight will be truncated.

Comment: Yes, I use SQL server and entity framework. The main reason why I decided to truncate the decimal value was because I always stumbled upon this error "argument exception parameter value is out of range decimal", so I then changed the decimal declaration to decimal(38, 30) in both SQL server and in entity framework to handle high precision decimals. It worked for in some 
 object but in the end I received another error "Coversion overflow".